# Extracting text from a string between multiple sets of parentheses in python

Tags: python-2.7

If string=`Firstname Lastname (email1@place.edu) Firstname2 Lastname2 (email2@place.edu)`
I want a to create a new stringstring `email1@place.edu,email2@place.edu`

I tried

```
string= string.partition('(')[-1].partition(')')[0]
```

but then I get `email1@place.edu) Firstname2 Lastname2 (email2@place.edu`

How can I split this string?

Answer (score 0):

```
string.split()
```

you can tell Python what you'd like to `split()` on by passing an argument.  [see the docs for more functionality](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split).

The `split()` method will leave you with a `list` which you can iterate through to access each item individually -- using either a [for loop](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#for) or [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) in this case.

You should always check google and the documentation before posting a (*specific*) question to SO, so you receive the best feedback you can.

EDIT:

If you're just trying to access the string b/w parentheses, you can use regex or python's [`find()` method](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_find.htm)

```
string = "Firstname Lastname (email1@place.edu) Firstname2 Lastname2 (email2@place.edu)"
stringlist = string.split()
email_addresses = [item[1:-1] for item in stringlist if "(" in item and ")" in item]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use regular expressions.

```
import re 
regexp_pattern = '\([^\(\r\n]*\)'
st = "Firstname Lastname (email1@place.edu) Firstname2 Lastname2 (email2@place.edu)"
a = re.findall(regexp_pattern, st) #this gives you the list ['(email1@place.edu)','(email2@place.edu)']
b = ''.join(a)[1:-1] #this gives you the string 'email1@place.edu)(email2@place.edu'
b.replace(")(", ",") #this gives you the string 'email1@place.edu,email2@place.edu'
```

Of course, you can do it shorter if you like that more (I do):

```
import re 
regexp_pattern = '\([^\(\r\n]*\)'
st = "Firstname Lastname (email1@place.edu) Firstname2 Lastname2 (email2@place.edu)"
''.join(re.findall(regexp_pattern, st))[1:-1].replace(")(", ",")
```